# how to extract SVG properties?

Tags: ubuntu, svg

I am viewing an SVG file in the file-viewing application "Eye of Mate", which shows the following SVG properties:

[image]

however, when searching the fields, I see

`<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="460.8pt" height="345.6pt"` within the SVG.  These numbers are different than the `Properties` that I see in the window.

How can I extract 576 and 432 from this file?  The numbers don't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a direct association between the size in pixels and the size in points.  When each of the values in points is multiplied by 1.25, the result is pixels.